# Unsetting variable at reference in php

Tags: php, reference

I have a class which contains an array of objects and has methods to return an object from that array by reference. There is also a method to unset an object from the array.

However if I have a variable that references an object from the array, and that element is unset, the variable still has a reference to it. What do I need to do in the remove method that will destroy that object for good, including references to it.

```
class myClass
{
    public $objectList = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $objectList[] = new myObject();
    }

    public function &getObjectByReference()
    {
         return $this->objectList[0];
    }

    public function removeObject()
    {
        unset($this->objectList[0]);
    }
}
$myClass = new myClass();
$referencedObject = $myClass->getObjectByReference(); 
// this can now use the methods from myObject
$myClass-> removeObject(); 
// supposed to delete the object from memory. However $referencedObject is still
// able to use all the methods from myObject.
```

So thats the problem I am having, I need to be able to remove from the array and delete the object from memory so variables that reference that object are no longer usable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing:

```
$referencedObject = &$myClass->getObjectByReference();
```

Is $referencedObject still there after putting in that &?

Answer (score 0):

To create a reference from a return value both the function must return by reference (you already do so) and the assignment has to by by reference. So you should write:

```
$referencedObject =& $myClass->getObjectByReference();
```

If you do this the reference really will be destroyed.

But if you want to do destroy all variables having this object as value (and which are **not** references) then this is impossible. You can only remove the real references, not variables having the same value ;)

Comment: I tried doing it that way, but when calling print_r($referencedObject) it is still showing all of its member variables so it can't be gone?

Answer (score 0):

Php is working with garbage collector : if there is still a reference to the object then the object is not deleted.

```
unset($this->objectList[0])
```

Does not delete the object but the value in $this->objectList, the object still exists since he is referenced by $referencedObject.

One solution : when you delete the object, tell him he is being deleted and in that object you have a boolean "isDeleted". Then for every method of that object, check if isDeleted is true and in that case, just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of PHP's garbage collector. To make sure a caller doesn't maintain a reference to your object you have to ensure they can never touch the original object. Here is an idea:

```
class myClass
{
    public $objectList = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $objectList[] = new Wrapper(new myObject());
    }

    public function getObject()
    {
         return $this->objectList[0];
    }

    public function removeObject()
    {
        $this->objectList[0]->emptyWrapper();
        unset($this->objectList[0]);
    }
}



class Wrapper {

    private $object;

    public function __construct($object) {
        $this->object = $object;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->object, $method), $args);
    }

    public function __get($attr) {
        return $this->object->$attr;
    }

    public function __set($attr, $value) {
        $this->object->$attr = $value;
    }

    public function emptyWrapper() {
        $this->object = null;
    }

}
```

You can use this wrapper idea or you can use *forced indirection* and handles. I might prefer using forced indirection instead; otherwise, a caller can still keep the wrapper object alive - though it is fairly cheap.

```
class myClass
{
    public $objectList = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $objectList[] = new myObject();
    }

    public function getObjectHandle() {
        return 0;
    }

    public function removeObject($h)
    {
        unset($this->objectList[$h]);
    }

    public function call($h, $method, $args) {
        call_user_func(array($this->objectList[$h], $method), $args);
    }

    public function get($h, $attr) {
        return $this->objectList[$h]->$attr;
    }

    public function set($h, $attr, $value) {
        $this->objectList[$h]->$attr = $value;
    }

}

$myClass = new myClass();
$objectHandle = $myClass->getObjectHandle();
// example method call
$myClass->call($objectHandle, 'some_method', array('arg1', 'arg2')); 
$myClass->removeObject($objectHandle);
```